# 6000 mysql запросов - слишком долго

Tags: sql, mysql

При загрузке окна выполняется ~ 6000 mysql запросов. Общее время выпонения 22 сек. Оптимизировать каждый запрос в отдельности смысла не вижу, т.к. каждый из них по отдельности выполняется оптимально. Какими способами можно ускорить? 22 сек недостаточный показатель.

Comment: А кэшировать запросы не пробывали средствами PHP? Или хотя бы половину из них? Или у Вас они все время изменяются?

Comment: 22 секунды с учетом скорости клиента! это тоже важно учитывать!

Comment: ну и пусть клиент грузит кэшированные запросы, если таковые можно реализовать конечно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придется анализировать запросы.
1000 запросов к одной таблице, которые возвращают по одному значению, возможно получится заменить одним, который вернет 1000 значений.

Comment: самое разумное. я не могу представить, зачем гонять 6000 запросов на один пользовательский view (не СУБДшный view, а view как в MVC).

Comment: Пересмотреть коренным образом алгоритм/архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Сокращайте количество запросов, или используйте [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Уменьшить количество SQL запросов - очевидно же.

Что это за страница с 6000 запросов - не Битрикс старой версии, случайно?

Comment: не битрикс --- http://www.google.ru/search?ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wfSajaxSearchCategoryFCKeditor